# Firebase Cloud Message does not work tottaly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud

I added Firebase Cloud Messaging in my work project. When I try to send PUSH message by firebase console - all android virtual devices receive PUSH, but my real device(with mobile INTERNET) does not receive PUSH. I created separately test project, with same code and vualya it's work for all devices(AVD and my real device). Where is problem?

Comment: take device Token of real device and try to send push notification manually, It may happen that your real device Token is registered with FCM.

Comment: I lost about 4 hours((. And solution was so simple. I just manually uninstalled app from device, cleared app cache, and installed app again. After that i recieve PUSH message on my real device. Thanks for advices.)

Comment: Please upvote my answer that other can also get help from this

Answer (score 0):

Important: Do Not Disturb can block notifications. Learn how to use Do Not Disturb.

If you would like to receive push notifications using the SubAssistant app, your device must meet the following requirements:

Sync your Google account with your phone

Go to the Settings section of your phone.
Go to Accounts and sync.
Make sure there are no errors when syncing your account with your phone.

Set notification volume on your phone to ON

Go to the Settings of your phone.
Go to Sound setting.
Go to Volume setting.
Set Notification volume to ON.

Ensure notifications for the SubAssistant app are ON
Go to the Settings of your phone
Go to Application manager (or Apps)
Find and select your-app
Ensure there is a checkmark next to Show Notifications.

Check the Notification Sound setting in the app

Open the SubAssistant app
Open the app menu (tap the green icon in the top-left corner)
Tap Settings
Tap Notification Sound
Select your desired sound, then tap OK

Answer (score 0):

I lost about 4 hours((. And solution was so simple. I just manually uninstalled app from device, cleared app cache, and installed app again. After that i recieve PUSH message on my real device. Thanks for advices.)